# using circshift to shift martix diagonally in matlab / octave

Tags: image, matlab, matrix, octave, diagonal

How can I shift a matrix cells diagonally?

**I have an image with horizontal lines see below:**
[image: Original horizontal lines Image]

**I use the snippet of code to shift the cells diagonally see below**

```
reshaped_output = imresize(repmat_rgb, [640, 480]); %reshape output
imwrite(reshaped_output,strcat('/tmp/img/','orig','.png')); %will create file without borders and use any resize in repmat

[row, col, dim] = size(reshaped_output);

diag_shift_rgb=zeros(row, col, dim); %preallocate array
for ii=1:col
  bb_r=circshift(reshaped_output(:,ii,1),ii-1);
  bb_g=circshift(reshaped_output(:,ii,2),ii-1);
  bb_b=circshift(reshaped_output(:,ii,3),ii-1);
  diag_shift_rgb(:,ii,1)=[bb_r]; %over write array
  diag_shift_rgb(:,ii,2)=[bb_g]; %over write array
  diag_shift_rgb(:,ii,3)=[bb_b]; %over write array
end

imwrite(diag_shift_rgb,strcat('/tmp/img/','diag','.png')); %will create file without borders and use any resize in repmat
```

**I do get shifted diagonal lines but the colors are off along with the shift what am I doing incorrectly?**

[image: Diagonal image]

Ps: I'm using Octave 4.0 which is similar to matlab

Another example with numbers

```
Input Example with numbers
1                     1                     1                     1
2                     2                     2                     2
3                     3                     3                     3
4                     4                     4                     4
5                     5                     5                     5
6                     6                     6                     6
7                     7                     7                     7


Output example with numbers of what I'm trying to get with the image
1                     7                     6                     5
2                     1                     7                     6
3                     2                     1                     7
4                     3                     2                     1
5                     4                     3                     2
6                     5                     4                     3
7                     6                     5                     4
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @rahnema1 the colors don't closely match when they should and if you take a look there seems to be more white in the output than the input.  The lines should be going diagonally which is correct also the output array size should also be the same as the original array size.

Comment: @rahnema1 I added another example with numbers.   Notice the diagonal tilt (look at the 1's and 2's) I'm trying to do the same with the color lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`diag_shift_rgb` is of type `double` but it should be of type `uint8` to be saved correctly:

```
diag_shift_rgb = zeros (row, col, dim, "uint8");
```